# IllegalStateException in IAB V3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am trying to impliment android in app billing v3 and my application crashes with the following error  **Can't start async operation (consume) because another async operation(consume) is in progress**

Stack trace is given below

```
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (consume) because another async operation(consume) is in progress.
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.seven.BillingHelper.IabHelper.flagStartAsync(IabHelper.java:711)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.seven.BillingHelper.IabHelper.consumeAsyncInternal(IabHelper.java:832)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.seven.BillingHelper.IabHelper.consumeAsync(IabHelper.java:623)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.seven.javalib.InAppBilling$15.run(InAppBilling.java:350)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-25 16:56:54.811: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reason in a previous try the method `flagEndAsync` hasnot been called, make sure that in `IabHelper` in all cases (success or failure) the method `flagEndAsync` is called.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen because `IabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` is not called in the `onActivityResult()` method of your activity.  You may want to verify that it is being called.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating all code. It's easier to make the flagEndSync method in your IabHelper public.

Then each time you make call to your IabHelper, call Mhelper.flagEndAsync() first. Then you know for sure you start with a clean Asynctask.

No crashes for me anymore.

Comment: What if there is really an async operation going on? If you call `flagEndAsync()` before each `flagStartAsync()`, there will be no point of using `mAsyncInProgress` flag.