# Android in-app billing: Can't start async operation because another async operation (is in progress)

Tags: android, android-billing

I am using the `IabHelper` utility classes, as recommended by Google's tutorial, and I'm being hit hard by this error. Apparently `IabHelper` can not run multiple async operations at the same time. I even managed to hit it by trying to start a purchase while the inventory taking was still in progress.

I have already tried to implement `onActivityResult` in my main class as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130044/android-billing-exception), but I don't even get a call to that method before the error hits. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066095/illegalstateexception-in-iab-v3) but I have no idea where to find this `flagEndAsync` method - it's not in the `IabHelper` class.

Now I'm looking for a way around this (without reimplementing the whole she-bang). The only solution I can think of is to create a boolean field `asyncActive` that is checked before an async task is started, and not do it if there is another task active. But that has many other problems, and doesn't work across activities. Also I'd prefer to have an async task queue up and run as soon as it's allowed to, instead of not running at all.

Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: For everyone reading this question, [b]scroll down![/b] and use the 'onActivityResult()' snippet there, that is the answer

Comment: Call mHelper.handleActivityResult() in onActivityResult() so flagAsync() gets called. See Google's TrivialDrive sample code.

Comment: None of these answers are really a clean solution. I would recommend using a single thread executor (Executor mExec = Executors.newSingleThreadExectuors()) and then building a wrapper class which makes each IAB call a blocking runnable that gets appropriately queued on this executor.

Answer (score 105):

A simple tricky solution

before calling **purchaseItem** method just add this line

```
  if (billingHelper != null) billingHelper.flagEndAsync();
```

so your code looks this way

```
 if (billingHelper != null) billingHelper.flagEndAsync();
 purchaseItem("android.test.purchased");
```

**Note:** don't forget to make public flagEndAsync() method in IabHelper if you call it from another package.

Comment: You mean before calling "launchPurchaseFlow" method, don't you?

Comment: I'm very disspointed in this library https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/ see all the open issues. Google does not seem to fix. I find it important...

Comment: :( May I know which issue you are facing ? @powder366

Comment: Had to fix it according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628155/android-in-app-billing-cant-start-launchpurchaseflow-because-launchpurchaseflo

Comment: It works greate, just don't forget to make public flagEndAsync() method in IabHelper if you call it from another package

Comment: Hack, use the answer below where the activity result is handled and you won't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem of overlapping async calls happening at once... which is why the library has this check in the first place. I actually used the method of maintaining my own async flag in a wrapper class, and firing off a thread which waits on that flag before starts the IABHelper's async methods. It's ugly, but actually does the job of queueing.

Comment: What does that flag do?

Comment: My users were ocasionally catching this error at 'inappbillingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener)' right after 'registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter)' in 'inappbillingHelper.startSetup(new inappbillingHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()' in 'onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)'. Thus I'm adding 'inappbillingHelper.flagEndAsync()' before queryInventoryAsync calls too, hopefully solving more odd errors than it creates.

Comment: Simples e funcional ,Obrigado!

Comment: when I used this code 
I had this exception
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
IabHelper was disposed of, so it cannot be used.

Answer (score 80):

Make sure that you call the IabHelper's `handleActivityResult` in the Activity's `onActivityResult`, and **NOT** in the Fragment's `onActivityResult`.

The following code snippet is from TrivialDrive's [MainActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java#L446):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (mHelper == null) return;

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

**Update:**

- There is now a [In-app Billing Version 3 API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html) (what was the version in 2013?)
- The code sample has moved to [Github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample). Snippet above edited to reflect current sample, but is logically the same as before.

Comment: i literally pulled my hair on this one LOL
Thanks

Comment: This is the *correct* answer. All other solutions are a hack. This works even if destroying activities, etc. This is the correct flow.

Comment: for in-app billing with fragments, see this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434995/529663](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434995/529663)

Comment: This is perfect. Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Adding if (mHelper == null) return; resolved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: The asker wrote that he already implemented the exact same code in the onActivityResult() method (see referred SO link) and it still doesn't work. So how is that the correct answer?

Comment: @Damnum the first sentence of this answer is the difference.

Comment: Ok it might help people who used the method on a fragment. Having implemented the version you recommended, my users still experience the issue in around 1% of the time, which is enough to lose a lot of money. I can't believe google doesn't provide a library for this, instead of releasing buggy code samples. Amazon does it so much better.

Comment: Same as Damnum, I am still getting errors with this, of course much less, but still really problematic.

Answer (score 41):

This was not easy to crack but I found the needed workarounds. Quite disappointed with Google lately, their Android web sites have become a mess (very hard to find useful info) and their sample code is poor. When I was doing some Android development a few years ago it all went so much easier! This is yet another example of that...

Indeed IabUtil is buggy, it does not properly call off its own async tasks. The complete set of necessary workarounds to stabilise this thing:

1) make method `flagEndAsync` public. It is there, just not visible.

2) have every listener call `iabHelper.flagEndAsync` to make sure the procedure is marked finished properly; it seems to be needed in all listeners.

3) surround calls with a `try/catch` to catch the `IllegalStateException` which may occur, and handle it that way.

Comment: Or you can replace `IllegalStateException` thrown in `flagEndAsync` with some new exception class inherited from `Exception` to understand where you should place `try/catch` blocks. This force code static analyzer generate errors where you custom exception didn't handled.

Comment: As mentioned below by user2574426, the repo includes several fixes to IabHelper.java that address this.  For whatever reason, my SDK (API 17) example code does NOT include these fixes.  Visit https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/ for details.

Comment: MutantXenu, Shall I proceed with user2574426 solution with a closed eyes :) please advice.

Comment: now i have this exception on flagStartAsync ... what's going on?

Comment: I'm dissapointed too. Had numerous problems so far both with In-App Billing and these "helper" utils.

Comment: @MutantXenu the version in that repo does not fix this. I used that Util directory, no difference

Comment: I was disappointed too, until I found out I just did not adapt the code correctly. The 'OnActivityResult()' pointed out further below fixed it for me. We coders are just not good at following directions ;)

Comment: The comment right above this one sums up my experience. Adding the onActivityResult() to the activity was the missing link. Things seem to be working really well now.

Comment: Hack, use the answer below where the activity result is handled and you won't have to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 15):

I ended up doing something similar to Kintaro. But added mHelper.flagEndAsync() to the end of the catch.  The user still gets the toast but by the next time they push the purchase button, the async operation has been killed and the purchase button is ready to go again.

```
if (mHelper != null) {
    try {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, item, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
    }       
    catch(IllegalStateException ex){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please retry in a few seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mHelper.flagEndAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Liked this simple approach although it is not the best.

Answer (score 12):

Find `flagEndAsync()` inside **IabHelper.java** file  and change it to a **public** function.

Before trying purchase call `flagEndAsync()` for your **IabHelper**

You must do somthig like this code :

```
mHelper.flagEndAsync();
mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(AboutActivity.this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "payload-string");
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue until I stumbled upon [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831503/iabhelper-purchasefinishedlistener). I'm including a touched up version of the code found in the other thread that you need to include in your Activity that initialises the purchase.

```java
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    // NOTE: handleActivityResult() will update the state of the helper,
    // allowing you to make further calls without having it exception on you
    if (billingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        handlePurchaseResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

    // What you would normally do
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple trick that did it for me was to create a method in IabHelper:

```
public Boolean getAsyncInProgress() {
    return mAsyncInProgress;
}
```

and then in your code, just check:

```
if (!mHelper.getAsyncInProgress())
    //launch purchase
else
    Log.d(TAG, "Async in progress already..)
```

Answer (score 6):

Really annoying issue. Here is a quick and dirty solution that is not perfect code wise, but that is user friendly and avoids bad ratings and crashes:

```
if (mHelper != null) {
        try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, item, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
        }       
        catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please retry in a few seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

This way the user just has to tap another time (2 times at worst) and gets the billing popup

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Just check for the onActivityResult requestCode on the activity and if it matches the PURCHASE_REQUEST_CODE you used on the purchase just pass it to the fragment.

When you add or replace the fragment in the FragmentTransaction just set a tag:

```
fTransaction.replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
```

Then on your activity's onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PurchaseFragment.PURCHASE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        PurchaseFragment fragment = getSuportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PurchaseFragment.class.getNAme());
        if(fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you code in fragment then you this code in IabHelper.java

```
void flagStartAsync(String operation) {
    if (mAsyncInProgress) {
        flagEndAsync();
    }
    if (mAsyncInProgress) throw new IllegalStateException("Can't start async operation (" +
            operation + ") because another async operation(" + mAsyncOperation + ") is in progress.");
    mAsyncOperation = operation;
    mAsyncInProgress = true;
    logDebug("Starting async operation: " + operation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can get the latest IabHelper.java file here: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/source/browse/

The March 15th version fixed this for me. (Note other files with no changes were committed on the 15th)

I still had to fix one crash that happened during testing caused by a null intent extras when "android.test.canceled" was the sent SKU. I changed:

```
int getResponseCodeFromIntent(Intent i) {
    Object o = i.getExtras().get(RESPONSE_CODE);
```

to:

```
int getResponseCodeFromIntent(Intent i) {
    Object o = i.getExtras() != null ? i.getExtras().get(RESPONSE_CODE) : null;
```

Comment: Hi, Just rechecking? did you upload an app with this solution and you are satisfied with it? Shall I proceed with your solution with a closed eyes? please advice :)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue occasionally, and in my case I've tracked it down to the fact that if the onServiceConnected method in IabHelper can be called more than once if the underlying service disconnects and reconnects (e.g. due to an intermittent network connection).

The specific operations in my case were "Can't start async operation (refresh inventory) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress."

The way that my app is written, I can't call launchPurchaseFlow until after I've had a completed queryInventory, and I only call queryInventory from my onIabSetupFinished handler function.

The IabHelper code will call this handler function whenever its onServiceConnected is called, which can happen more than once.

The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) for onServiceDisconnected says:

> Called when a connection to the Service has been lost. This typically happens when the 
>   process hosting the service has crashed or been killed. This does not remove the 
>   ServiceConnection itself -- this binding to the service will remain active, and you will 
>   receive a call to onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder) when the Service is next 
>   running.

which explains the problem.

Arguably, IabHelper shouldn't call the onIabSetupFinished listener function more than once, but on the other hand it was trivial to fix the problem in my app by simply not calling queryInventory from within this function if I've already done it and got the results.

Answer (score 1):

Another major issue with the IabHelpr class is the poor choice of throwing RuntimeExcptions (IllegalStateException) in multiple methods. Throwing RuntimeExeptions from your own code in most cases is not desirable due to the fact that they are *unchecked exceptions*. That is like sabotaging your own application- if not caught, these exceptions will bubble up and crash your app.

The solution to this is to implement your own *checked exception* and change the IabHelper class to throw it, instead of the IllegalStateException. That will force you to handle this exception everywhere it could be thrown in your code at compile time.

Here is my custom exception:

```
public class MyIllegalStateException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Parameterless Constructor
    public MyIllegalStateException() {}

    //Constructor that accepts a message
    public MyIllegalStateException(String message)
    {
       super(message);
    }
}
```

Once we make the changes in the IabHelper class, we can handle our checked exception in our code where we call the class methods. For example:

```
try {
   setUpBilling(targetActivityInstance.allData.getAll());
} catch (MyIllegalStateException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is a piece of a really good solution! I would recommend coming up with some systematic way of handling the exception other than just printing the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I didn't implement the method onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
            int resultCode,
            Intent data)
{
    try
    {
        if (billingHelper == null)
        {
            return;
        } else if (!billingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am also facing this issue but i resolved this but i resolved using

```
IabHelper mHelpermHelper = new IabHelper(inappActivity, base64EncodedPublicKey);
  mHelper.flagEndAsync();
```

The above method stop all the flags. Its work for me must check

Answer (score 0):

This answer directly addresses the problem that @Wouter has seen...

It is true that `onActivityResult()` must be triggered, like many people have said. However, the bug is that Google's code isn't triggering `onActivityResult()` in certain circumstances, i.e. when you're pressing your [BUY] button twice when running the debug build of your app.

Additionally, one major problem is that the user may be in a shaky environment (i.e. Bus or subway) and presses your [BUY] button twice... suddenly you've got yourself an exception !

At least Google fixed this embarrassing exception https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/commit/07b085b32a62c7981e5f3581fd743e30b9adb4ed#diff-b43848e47f8a93bca77e5ce95b1c2d66

**Below is what I implemented in the same class where `IabHelper` is instantiated (for me, this is in the Application class) :**

```
/**
 * invokes the startIntentSenderForResult - which will call your activity's onActivityResult() when it's finished
 * NOTE: you need to override onActivityResult() in your activity.
 * NOTE2: check IAB code updates at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util
 * @param activity
 * @param sku
 */
protected boolean launchPurchaseWorkflow(Activity activity, String sku)
{
    if (mIabIsInitialized)
    {
        try
        {
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(
                    activity,
                    sku,
                    Constants.PURCHASE_REQUEST_ID++,// just needs to be a positive number and unique
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener,
                    Constants.DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD);
            return true;//success
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            return launchPurchaseWorkflow(activity, sku);//recursive call
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;//failure - not initialized
    }
}
```

My [BUY] button calls this `launchPurchaseWorkflow()` and passes the SKU and the activity the button is in (or if you're in a fragment, the enclosing activity)

**NOTE:** be sure to make `IabHelper.flagEndAsync()` public.

Hopefully, Google will improve this code in the near future; this problem is about 3 years old and it's still an ongoing problem :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple

1.) Make the mAsyncInProgress variable visible outside of IabHelper

```
public boolean isAsyncInProgress() {
    return mAsyncInProgress;
}
```

2.) Use this in your Activity like:

```
...
if (mIabHelper.AsyncInProgress()) return;
mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(...);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A little-modified version of NadtheVlad's answer that works like charm

```
private void makePurchase() {

    if (mHelper != null) {
        try {
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), ITEM_SKU, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            makePurchase();
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is simple, just put the `launchPurchaseFlow()` thing in a method and use recursion in the catch block. You still need to make `flagEndAsync()` public from the `IabHelper` class.

Answer (score -2):

I have same issue, but it resolved!
I think you must be not run "launchPurchaseFlow" on UI thread, try to run launchPurchaseFlow on UI thread,
it would be working fine!

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(mActivity, item, 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener,username);
            }
        });
```

Comment: no need to modify anything on IabHelper, just run launchPurchaseFlow on UI thread!