# Why does Android's 'TrivialDrive v3 Billing Sample' not allow multiple async calls?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm using the utility methods from Android's 'TrivialDrive v3 Billing Sample', and as a lot of people have, I've been getting an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress.

This was addressed in quite a few threads (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628155/android-in-app-billing-cant-start-launchpurchaseflow-because-launchpurchaseflo) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575605/android-in-app-billing-cant-start-async-operation-because-another-async-operat)), and all places suggest try/catch or changing the 'async operation running' state to avoid that crash.

Those approaches don't make sense to me, since the first one requires me to implement retry mechanisms/errors throughout my app and the latter is messing with the flow of that lib (you might as well delete that "throws illegal state" code).

**My question is:** what is the reason for the "1 async operation at a time" restriction in IabHelper?

If there is a real reason, then maybe each method should throw an error that will force the developer to address it. If there is not, I think removing the 'throwing illegal state...' code should be removed.