# Error while trying to make purchases one after other

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am trying to make a series of inapp purchases one after other. This is how the code is setup. Make a call to purchase item by calling launchPurchaseFlow.

Now on public void onIabPurchaseFinished() I make the next call for purchase. The first call works fine. But the second call fails by throwing the exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(launchPurchaseFlow) is in progress.
```

How to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Well clearly it is already running and not finished yet. You need to show your full code where this is called to get any real help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the IABHelper class?

If so, some people have reported success making the `flagEndAsync` method public and calling it before starting a new purchase.

More info: [Android in-app billing: Can't start async operation because another async operation (is in progress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575605/android-in-app-billing-cant-start-async-operation-because-another-async-operat)

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely because the first request has not yet finished; it would finish when you return from onIabPurchaseFinished(); the async request is *not* finished inside that function.

Comment: Most likely? the error already tells him precisely this, this unfortunately doesn't answer the question of how to fix it